# Delphi Firemonkey ios Background Fetch

Tags: ios, delphi, background, firemonkey

i'm trying to use delphi Firemonkey to develop an iphone App. I need to download an xml every x minutes and process it, if there are new data send notification. It's very easy if the app is in use, but i can't find the way to use this procedure when the app is in background....

Please help me...

Tnx a lot...But i can't do this....
this is my simpliest code that doesn't work... What is my error???

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP1 : TIdHTTP;
  MyFile          : TFileStream;
  Notification: TNotification;
  UIApp : UIApplication;
begin
  UIApp := TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
  UIApp.setIdleTimerDisabled(True);

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure ()
  var
I: Integer;
Total: Integer;
  begin
Total := 0;

while true do
  begin

    // Carico l'XML
    MyFile:= TFileStream.Create(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar+'listticket',fmCreate);

    IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.google.com', MyFile);
    IdHTTP1.Free;
    MyFile.Free;

  end;

sleep(5*60*1000);

TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
  procedure ()
  begin
  end);
  end).Start;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these articles to get you started.

[Disable The IOS Device Idle Time Out In Your Delphi XE5 Firemonkey App](http://www.fmxexpress.com/disable-the-ios-device-idle-time-out-in-your-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-app/)

[Programatically Disable the Idle Timer on iOS using the ObjectiveC Bridge](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1387)

[Providing background services support to your iOS apps with Delphi](http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/10/providing-background-services-support-to-your-ios-apps-with-delphi/)

[Handle Android And IOS Lifecycle Events In Delphi XE5 Firemonkey](http://www.fmxexpress.com/handle-android-and-ios-lifecycle-events-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/)

Comment: Ok tnx a lot, but i can't find the ability to execute commands when the app is in background.. I open the app, i login, i press the home button, here my app continue executing process for 10 seconds... then stop!!!
I used the <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
   <string>location</string>
 </array>
But no more events when the app is in background.

tnx a lot

Comment: Do your downloading in a worker thread, and disable the idle timer while that thread is running, or at least while the app is in the background. You are not using GPS so `location` is not an appropriate background mode for your app, try `fetch` instead: "The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network."

Comment: Tnx a lot...But i can't do this.... this is my simpliest code that doesn't work... What is my error???
I posted my code in the first...
TNX A LOT

Comment: Rather than say it doesn't work, why not explain what it actually does, and how it is different than what you are expecting.

Comment: Oh yes, excuse me!! It worldclient perfect in foreground!!! But when the app goes in background it stops downloading this file!!! This is a demo file, in the working app it is a php page sending an xml! After this download the file shoud be processed and, in case of changes it should send a notification!!! When the app goes in background this thred is been processed for 10 seconds then stops his execution!! It's my first app and is an app not for redistribution but it could be very useful for download and process data from my server!!!

Comment: You are likely encountering the following known bug in `TThread.Synchronize()`: [#123579 TThread.Synchronize() and TThread.Queue() do not work correctly in FireMonkey](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123579).  When your app goes in the background, the main message queue likely stops receiving UI messages, and so `TThread.Synchronize()` blocks until the app comes back into the foreground and starts receiving UI messages again. There is a workaround: "manually call `CheckSynchronize()` in a timer in the main thread."

Comment: Why are you `Synchronize()`'ing a blank anonymous procedure in the first place? If you remove that, your thread will likely start working correctly while the app is in the background.

Comment: Yes i added the fetch background!!! If i take the app in foreground for hours it goes always and download always the file!! When it goes in background, adding a small check, it goes for 10 seconds then stops!! If i rebring the app in foregroun it restarts!!! So in my opinion, is ios blocking this but i can't find the way to understand why!!!

Comment: See my comment above. It is likely not iOS's fault at all, but more likely is FireMonkey's fault.

Comment: Tnx a lot... But nothing... I removed the part of code for Synchronize().. but the result is the same... The file is being downloaded when the app is in foreground, if i press the home button it stops (no more file download), if i rebring it to foreground it restarts from where it was.... My ios is the simulator of a 7.1 Xcode 5, the delphi is a trial version of XE6...

Comment: I tried also a timer... but it's the same... When the app goes to background it stops... The only way is to execute the command in a loop like procedure button1 action; sleep(xxxx); button1Click; but, obviously it blocks all the others process!!!

Comment: This still smells like a thread blockage/deadlock to me. You are going to have to debug into the code while it is running to find out what is really going on.